# How to get the sum of each row in java using multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, multidimensional-array

So i'm new at java and I'm currently trying to learn how to use array. So what i'm trying to do is to create a program the will as the user the numbers of rows and column and print the sum of the 2d array.

So the output should be like this:

```
Enter the number of row:2
Enter the number column:2 

Enter a number:1
Enter a number:2
Enter a number:3
Enter a number:4

Output: 

1 2 3
3 4 7
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter the number of row:2
Enter the number column:2 

Enter a number:1
Enter a number:2
Enter a number:3
Enter a number:4

Output: 

1 2
3 4
```

Somehow i cant find a way to sum each row.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of row: ");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of column: ");
        int column = input.nextInt();

        int [][] array = new int[row][column];

        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<column; j++){
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();

            }

        }


        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<column; j++){
                System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

I've been trying to do this for the past 3 hours and i cant seem to find a way to sum each row . I'm pretty new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So basically, have a variable initialized for each row to calculate sumof all elements of the given row. Display it after the elements are displayed

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of row: ");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of column: ");
        int column = input.nextInt();

        int [][] array = new int[row][column];

        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<column; j++){
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();

            }

        }


        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){

            int s = 0; // this variable calculates the sum
            for(int j = 0; j<column; j++){

                s+=a[i][j]; // summing elements of that row
                System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");

            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what was the problem, *Try this* won't help the OP or future readers to understand.

Comment: Why did you initialize s before the second loop?

Comment: @BrianAaronBermudez variable 's' calculates sum for the entire row. Hence, outside that row, we initialize it to 0.

Comment: Don't forget to close scanner

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);/*initializing the variable input with   
        new Scanner object*/


        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows");/*getting the number of rows 
        and columns of the 2D array as an user input*/

        int noOfRows=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns");
        int noOfColumns=input.nextInt();

        int newArr[][] = new int[noOfRows][noOfColumns];//creation of the 2D array

        for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfRows ; i++) {/*Goal of this for loop is to assign the 
        userInpts to the array indexes*/
            for(int j = 0 ; j < noOfColumns ; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");/*Getting the user inputs to 
                store in the array*/
                newArr[i][j] = input.nextInt();


            }
    }

     for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfRows ; i++) {/*Goal of this for loop is printing the 
     array and sum of the row at the end of the each row*/
          int sumofTheRow = 0;/*This is the variable which holds the sum of the 
          current row so initial value is 0 */
        for(int j = 0 ; j < noOfColumns ; j++) {
            sumofTheRow  += newArr[i][j];/*so inside the inner for loop sumOfTheRow 
             will be calculated by adding the elements in the row one by one*/
            System.out.print(newArr[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println(sumofTheRow);//Calculated sum of the row will be displayed 

        /*So now if i is less than noOfRows then again it will increment the value of i by one and move to the next row */

    }
    input.close();/*closing the scanner variable to avoid memory leaks --> [ now garbage collector will free the memory area of scanner object  by collecting the scanner object]*/









}
```

}